# Chrome displays radio and checkbox buttons differently localhost and live

Tags: css, google-chrome, angularjs

I'm currently making an angular site using yeoman and bootstrap 3. I'm having some issues with some of the styling in chrome. Everything just seems a bit off, and i can't work out what it is. One particular example is with the radio buttons. When I run the node.js server and view the site on localhost, the radio buttons look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHQ1T.png). And then when I push the site live, the radio buttons look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rI41G.png).

It seems like chrome is rendering a bunch of css elements slightly differently between localhost and live. Does anyone know what might be causing this issue or if there is a simple solution? I read somewhere else that it might be due to the adblocker plus extension I had installed, but disabling that hasn't made a difference.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, its a small but annoying bug...

[image: Picture 1]
[image: Picture 2]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok so it turns out to be something very stupid on my side. Chrome was automatically zooming into sites on local host, and this meant that all the radio buttons and checkboxes were changing style and the css was going off. I hope this helps anyone else suffering from the same mistake!

Comment: just ran into this one, absolutely horrible, was almost pulling my hair out !

Comment: So many times stack overflow questions like this solve my issues. Big thanks for sharing your realisation!

Comment: @nikek no problem! Glad it helped you out too

Comment: In fact this is related to my post here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38786471/chrome-checkboxes-and-radios-rendering-at-different-zoom-levels

Answer (score 0):

It looks like one screenshot is on  a MAc and another is from a PC. You can try moving out of Yeoman and launch the file locally to compare the difference. It is more to do with your Yeoman configuration that Angularjs.

Comment: They're both actually on a mac. I will have a go moving it out of yeoman though. Thanks