# Chrome Checkboxes and radios rendering at different zoom levels

Tags: google-chrome, checkbox, radio-button

Chrome (Mac OS) checkbox and radios are only displaying correctly at 100% zoom level  :
[image: 100% zoom level]

Any other zoom level will show :

[image: Any other zoom level]

Any clue and workaround about that ? Safari, Firefox EDGE, Chrome Windows are working well.